# How to call all deployed instance of a Ignite Service

Tags: java, service, ignite

I have a certain service that is deployed in a cluster group in an Apache Ignite cluster.
Cluster group size is 3. 
Total Number of service instances = 3. 
Instance per node = 1.

No whenever I want to execute the service, I can get an handle to once of the service instances on a node only.

But I want to execute the service on all the nodes. 
ie. on all three nodes.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for remote service invocation. If that's the case, you can use service proxy: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-example#service-proxy

Comment: yes. But this will only envoke one service instance on one node. Now in my case there is only one service on one node. And I want the service to be executed on all nodes with one call. 
The above mentioned method does not provide for this

Comment: That's a weird use case for service grid. I would recommend to look at compute grid instead: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid. It allows to execute any arbitrary piece of logic on the cluster and provides full control. For example, you can broadcast a closure to all nodes or to a cluster group.

Comment: Ok. I was assuming I do it the other way, where I could do a targeted call on a service and achieve the required objectives. Will try with the compute grid as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-singletons), you can use node singletons to achieve that level of distribution for a service:

> **Node Singleton**
>
> You can deploy a per-node singleton service. Ignite will guarantee that there is always one instance of the service running on each node. Whenever new nodes are started within the cluster group, Ignite will automatically deploy one instance of the service on every new node.

The comment refers to the following code snippets:

```
IgniteServices svcs = ignite.services();
//The .services() method has an overload, to which you can pass a cluster group
svcs.deployNodeSingleton("myNodeSingleton", new MyService());
```

And its alternative:

```
svcs.deployMultiple("myNodeSingleton", new MyService(), 0, 1);
```

I supposed that by "service instance", you meant "a running instance of the same service implementation".

Comment: Yes i am using a Node singleton, but what I want to do is that execute every service that are present on all nodes.

Comment: Then using the compute grid is more appropriate as you can send a runnable on each node of your specified group

Comment: Ok. I was assuming I do it the other way, where I could do a targeted call on a service and achieve the required objectives. Will try with the compute grid as well. Thanks